# como transformar uma saída dput em um data.frame novamente no R?

Tags: r, data.frame

Eu tenho um data.frame e gostaria de armazena-lo no formato texto dentro do meu docx. Verifiquei que a função `dput` pode fazer isso muito bem. Porém gostaria de saber como faço para converter essa saída do `dput` novamente em um data.frame legivel pelo R.

Veja o meu exemplo para o data.frame `saude`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

aplicando o dput à `suade`

```
dput(saude)
```

minha saída é:

> structure(list(Diastolic_BP_mmHg = c(0.93, -0.43, 0.58, 0.19,
> -2.05, -0.43, 1.39, -0.7, 0.81, -0.31), Sistolic_BP_mmHg = c(0.82,
> -0.05, 0.46, 0.82, -1.98, -0.37, 1.21, -1.19, 0.62, -0.33), Peso_Kg = c(0.21,
> 1.43, 1.28, -0.55, 0.06, -0.85, -1.46, -0.39, -0.85, 1.12), Altura_cm = c(0.36,
> 1.6, 0.36, -0.57, 0.51, -1.19, -0.88, -0.73, -0.88, 1.44)), class = c("tbl_df",  "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L))

Como eu poderia converter essa saída novamente no data.frame acima?

Comment: Veja `?dget`. Para recriar o df da pergunta basta atribuir o valor do comando a uma variável, que passa a ser o nome do objeto (um df).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu encontrei a resposta muito simples em: https://lhmet.github.io/adar-ebook/exportando-e-recuperando-objetos-do-r-no-formato-textual.html

basta somente atribuir uma variável ao texto de saída:

```
saude_df<-structure(list(Diastolic_BP_mmHg = c(0.93, -0.43, 0.58, 0.19, -2.05, -0.43, 1.39, -0.7, 0.81, -0.31), Sistolic_BP_mmHg = c(0.82, -0.05, 0.46, 0.82, -1.98, -0.37, 1.21, -1.19, 0.62, -0.33), Peso_Kg = c(0.21, 1.43, 1.28, -0.55, 0.06, -0.85, -1.46, -0.39, -0.85, 1.12), Altura_cm = c(0.36, 1.6, 0.36, -0.57, 0.51, -1.19, -0.88, -0.73, -0.88, 1.44)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

saude_df

Desta forma o texto volta a organizar as informações de forma inteleigível.